# The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

error: "invalid_request"
error_description: "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed."
hint: "Check the `code` parameter"
message: "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed."

```
$response = Http::asForm()->post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token', [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => 5,
        'client_secret' => 'TRYwOxai8MO5e5b8N4RNBDc4oLOykIBKY9919p3T',
        'scope' => "*"
    ]);

    return json_decode((string) $response->getBody(), true);
```

how to access this token in oauth ?

Comment: Already stated in the error message itself. You're missing the param `code` in the request for `authorization_code` grant type.

Comment: which parameters are missing ?

Answer (score 1):

For token Request, first you need to obtained a `authorization code` from authorization server and then you need to use that code in order to obtain the `access token`.
You've to include follwoing params in order to obtained access token.

```
client_id       Required. The client application's id.
client_secret   Required. The client application's client secret .
grant_type      Required. Must be set to authorization_code .
code            Required. The authorization code received from the authorization server.
redirect_uri    Required, Same uri which you've passed earlier during authorization code retrieval.
```